# JavaScript outputting a deck floor plan

Tags: javascript, css

I'm new to JavaScript. I need to output a floor plan of a deck following a calculation of how many boards needed, given the deck length and width, along with the board length and width. My calculations work but the floor plan is not outputting correctly. What should I change in the last for loop that will output a plan?

For example if there were 10 8x1-foot boards for a 16x5 foot deck, then it might look like this 
-------- --------
-------- --------
-------- --------
-------- --------
-------- --------

My code is below. I have a for loop that will give me a board of "---" based on the board length. Underneath that is my sad for loop for trying to output the floor plan of it based on the width of the deck(deckWidth) and length of it (deckLength).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var deckArea;
 var boardArea;
 var numBoards;
 var total;
 var dLength;
 var dWidth;
 var bLength;
 var bWidth;
 var bPrice;
 var planBoard = "";
 
 $("#deckLength").keyup(function(){
  if((isNaN(this.value) === false) && this.value !== "") {
   dLength = parseFloat(this.value);
  }
 });
 
 $("#deckWidth").keyup(function(){
  if((isNaN(this.value) === false) && this.value !== "") {
   dWidth = parseFloat(this.value);
  }
 });
 
 $("#boardLength").keyup(function(){
  if((isNaN(this.value) === false) && this.value !== "") {
   bLength = parseFloat(this.value);
  }
 });
 
 $("#boardWidth").keyup(function(){
  if((isNaN(this.value) === false) && this.value !== "") {
   bWidth = parseFloat(this.value);
  }
 });
 
 $("#boardPrice").keyup(function(){
  if((isNaN(this.value) === false) && this.value !== "") {
   bPrice = parseFloat(this.value);
  }
 });
 
 $("#deckcalc").on("click", function () {
  numBoards = 0;
  total = 0;
  
  deckArea = dLength * dWidth;
  boardArea = bLength * bWidth;
  numBoards = deckArea/boardArea;
  total = numBoards * bPrice;
  
  //output total to screen
  $("#cost").text("$"+total.toFixed(2));
  $("#boardsNeeded").text(numBoards);
  
  for(var y = 0; y < (bLength); y++) {
   planBoard += "-";
  }
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < dLength; i++) {
   "<br>";
   for (var x = 0; x < dWidth; x++) {
    document.getElementById("plan").innerHTML = planBoard;
   }
  }
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>deck Length</label><input type="text" id="deckLength" />
<label>deck Width</label><input type="text" id="deckWidth" />
<label>board Length</label><input type="text" id="boardLength" />
<label>board Width</label><input type="text" id="boardWidth" />
<label>board Price</label><input type="text" id="boardPrice" />
<button id="deckcalc">calcit</button>
<div id="plan"></div>
```

Comment: So? If you have an actual problem in there then you need to say exactly what it is.  Vague questions are not allowed here.  Questions should actually have a question mark in them too.

Comment: I just edited the post, I hope it gives more clarity to what I need.

Comment: Oh my goodness, you might want to read about the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.  Tons of repeated code here.

Comment: This line: `"<br>";` Isn't doing anything. You have to add it as a DOM node where you want it to be inserted, for instance add it to `planBoard += "<br>"`.

Comment: "*...then it might look like this*" - it *might* look like this, or it *will* look like this? Will the boards always be the same length? The same width?

Comment: @DavidThomas If done correctly, it will look like that. Until changed, the boards will have the same length and same width.

Comment: You'll make life a lot easier for yourself doing this in HTML5 canvas which is now widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you're overwriting the .innerHTML property every time through. You probably want to add to the property instead using `+=`:

Also, as noted in the comments, you want to add your `<br />` tag to the output as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var deckArea;
 var boardArea;
 var numBoards;
 var total;
 var dLength;
 var dWidth;
 var bLength;
 var bWidth;
 var bPrice;
 var planBoard = "";
 
 $("#deckLength").keyup(function(){
  if((isNaN(this.value) === false) && this.value !== "") {
   dLength = parseFloat(this.value);
  }
 });
 
 $("#deckWidth").keyup(function(){
  if((isNaN(this.value) === false) && this.value !== "") {
   dWidth = parseFloat(this.value);
  }
 });
 
 $("#boardLength").keyup(function(){
  if((isNaN(this.value) === false) && this.value !== "") {
   bLength = parseFloat(this.value);
  }
 });
 
 $("#boardWidth").keyup(function(){
  if((isNaN(this.value) === false) && this.value !== "") {
   bWidth = parseFloat(this.value);
  }
 });
 
 $("#boardPrice").keyup(function(){
  if((isNaN(this.value) === false) && this.value !== "") {
   bPrice = parseFloat(this.value);
  }
 });
 
 $("#deckcalc").on("click", function () {
  numBoards = 0;
  total = 0;
  
  deckArea = dLength * dWidth;
  boardArea = bLength * bWidth;
  numBoards = deckArea/boardArea;
  total = numBoards * bPrice;
  
  //output total to screen
  $("#cost").text("$"+total.toFixed(2));
  $("#boardsNeeded").text(numBoards);
  
  for(var y = 0; y < (bLength); y++) {
   planBoard += "-";
  }
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < dLength; i++) {
   planBoard += "<br>";
   for (var x = 0; x < dWidth; x++) {
    document.getElementById("plan").innerHTML += planBoard;
   }
  }
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>deck Length</label><input type="text" id="deckLength" />
<label>deck Width</label><input type="text" id="deckWidth" />
<label>board Length</label><input type="text" id="boardLength" />
<label>board Width</label><input type="text" id="boardWidth" />
<label>board Price</label><input type="text" id="boardPrice" />
<button id="deckcalc">calcit</button>
<div id="plan"></div>
```